# alloy-ui how do I change the scheduler to use 24h

Tags: scheduler, alloy-ui

Using this scheduler http://alloyui.com/tutorials/scheduler/ how would I change it to use 24h instead of AM/PM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you'll need to set the [isoTime](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerView.html#attr_isoTime) attribute on each supported `view`.

```
var dayView = new Y.SchedulerDayView({
                                       isoTime: true
                                     });

new Y.Scheduler(
  {
    boundingBox: '#myScheduler',
    date: new Date(2013, 3, 25),
    items: events,
    render: true,
    views: [dayView]
  }
);
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/tm8m1wk0/)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I didn't know it was called "iso" or "international standard time" or I would've found that attribute much sooner.